# GridView - set width of column in code behind (AutoGenerateColumns="true")

Tags: asp.net, gridview, width, code-behind, autogeneratecolumn

My GridView :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    AutoGenerateColumns="true"
    DataKeyNames="Role_id">
</asp:GridView>
```

In code behind :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
       //e.Row.Cells[2].Width = 120;                      // isn't working....
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[2].Width = new Unit(120);             // isn't working....
        TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[2];
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;           //**** does work!
        cell.BackColor = Color.LightGray;                       //**** does work!
        //cell.Width = 120;                               // isn't working....
        //e.Row.Cells[2].Width = new Unit("120px") ;      // isn't working....
        //e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "myGV_Cell_Width";    // isn't working....
    }
}
```

The GridView is populated successfully.
Notice that I **can** set the alignment and the backcolor of the column, but not its width.
I tried many solutions circulating around but none worked.
It always resizes the column to the longest content.
Can it be done at all...?

Comment: Just think, how can individual cells have different widths in a table. Column can have widths, not cells.

Comment: Rows can't have different column widths.  All this should be set with a style sheet.

Comment: Yes. I should practice my English. In the meanwhile I'm looking for a way to set the column's width from code behind. (I'll change the title, and thanks for the remark).

Comment: @wolfeh - I tried with style sheet (see my last line in the above code). In the css I have only :  width: 150px;    But that didn't help either. Somewhere I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure what it is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do it with the RowCreated event but I had to set the width of the grid and also set the grid to a table-layout:fixed

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    style="table-layout:fixed;" Width="1000px"
    OnRowCreated = "GridView1_RowCreated"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    AutoGenerateColumns="true"
    DataKeyNames="Role_id">
</asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

 e.Row.Cells[0].Width = New Unit("220px");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

asp:GridView renders to HTML tables so you just need to set the column width using CSS

```
th, td {
    width: 120px;
}
```

Comment: I have myStyleSheet.css where I put my styles. Adding the style you mentioned did not help (though it did some weird stuff to the pagination numbers. Third column [2] is still resizing to the longest content).

Comment: You can use Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) or Chrome (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles) page inspectors to see what styles apply to your HTML elements.